# Difference between returning a value and returning Promise.resolve() from a function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have problem in understanding that what happens when we simply return a value or when we return `Promise.resolve()` from a function. Specifically: I am trying to understand how promises chaining works. I am chaining methods and verifying whether the value reaches in the method which is last call to `then`. I just want to understand the difference between returning promises to `then`, returning `Promise.resolve()` to `then`, and returning just a value to `then`.

Comment: I am not concerned about where. It is just what reaches the then function when a promise is resolved or simply a value i returned.

Comment: So I am trying to understand how promises chaining works. I am chaining methods and verifying whether the value reaches in the method which is last call to then. I just want to understand the difference between returning promises to then, returning Promise.resolve() to then, and returning just a value to then. - updated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have problem in understanding that what happens when we simply return a value or when we return `Promise.resolve()` from a function.

So there are (at least) two different scenarios:

#### In just any old function

If it's just any old function (not a `then` or `catch` callback), then the difference is that `return value;` directly returns the value, whereas `return Promise.resolve(value);` returns a *promise* fulfilled with that value. It changes how the calling code uses the result. In the `return value;` case, the calling code just directly uses it. In the `return Promise.resolve(value);` case, the calling code needs to consume the promise, just like any other promise (and can't assume that the promise is already settled, even though it is).

If the function is meant to be the start of a promise chain, you'd use `return Promise.resolve(value);`. (There are use cases for this; for instance, if the function may or may not need to start an asynchronous process: In the branch that doesn't have to, you'd still return a promise because the branch that has to do something asynchronous has to return a promise.) If it isn't, you'd just use `return value;`.

#### In `then` or `catch` callback

> I am trying to understand how promises chaining works.

In that case, you're talking about `return value;` vs. `return Promise.resolve(value);` in a `then` or `catch` callback. That's easy: There's no point at all to `return Promise.resolve(value);` in a `then` or `catch` callback, it's redundant and unnecessary overhead; just use `return value;`.

`then` and `catch` always return promises. If your callback returns a simple value (`return value;`), the promise is fulfilled with that value. If your callback returns a *thenable* (loosely, a promise; e.g., `return Promise.resolve(value);`), then the promise returned by `then`/`catch` is *resolved to* that thenable: When the thenable is settled, the promise is settled the same way. (And if your `then` or `catch` callback throws an error, the promise is rejected with that error.)

There are valid reasons to return a promise from a `then` or `catch` callback, if you're starting a new asynchronous process in that callback; but if you have an immediate value ready, there's no point in wrapping it in a promise — `then` and `catch` already do that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Got my issue resolved.

Answer (score 6):

When you return `Promise.resolve()`, you wrap your result into a Promise, on which you can call `then` and make chain of `then`. This is preferable for a single type returns.

```js
function resolve() {
   return Promise.resolve(15);
}

resolve().then(value => console.log(value));
```

If you have a logic which depends on a call to the server and also you can have that result in the `cache`, you can have a function which in all cases returns you a Promise, so you can add `then` for the result of the Promise. Look at this pseudo-code.

I want my function in all cases return a Promise. So here if I have cached the `userId` I can just wrap the result into the Promise with `Promise.resolve`

```
function getUserData() {
   if(cache.hasUserId) {
      return Promise.resolve(cache.hasUserId); // Is used to let the `then` functions to be called
   } else {
      return myAjaxCall();
   }
}

getUserData().then(userId => /* */);
```

Base on comment. Wrap into the `Promise.resolve()`

```js
function add1(data) { 
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
               resolve(data + 1); 
         }); 
} 

function add2(data) { 
   return Promise.resolve(data + 2); 
} 

function printdata(data) { 
   console.log(data); 
}
```

Comment: function add1(data) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  resolve(data + 1);
 });
}



function add2(data) {
 return data + 2;
}

function printdata(data) {
 console.log(data);
}

Comment: Updated See the edited part. Here with `add1` and `add2` you can use `then`.

Comment: But when I simply return a value from add2 I can still cahin in a then call. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

A `Promise` is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The `Promise.resolve(value)` method returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value. If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state; if the value was a promise, that object becomes the result of the call to Promise.resolve; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value. [MDN Promise.reslove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Returning a value from a function is synchronous unlike `Promise.resolve()`